# EMR failed to bootstrap Airflow

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, airflow

I'm creating a bash to provide the enviroment to execute airflow, but for some reason the script don't work as well.

If I provide first the EMR and after that execute the script, it work's fine. But if I use the script to execute in custom activity don't work. I tried to change the commands to execute like sudo, but still not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

# check for master node
IS_MASTER=true
if [ -f /mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json ]
then
    IS_MASTER=`cat /mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json | tr -d '\n ' | sed -n 's|.*\"isMaster\":\([^,]*\).*|\1|p'`
fi


if [ "$IS_MASTER" = "true}" ]; 
    then
    # install mysql jdbc driver on sqoop
    wget -qN -O ~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz"
    tar -zxvf ~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz && rm ~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz

    sudo mv ~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib

    sudo chmod 744 /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar

    aws s3 cp s3://monet-datapipeline/scripts/emr_boostrap_scripts/airflow_boostrap ~/ --recursive --exclude "*.sh"

    #create enviroment for airflow
    virtualenv airflowenv -p python3 
    source ~/airflowenv/bin/activate

    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install airflow
    pip install boto3

    airflow initdb

    mv ~/carriola/airflow.cfg ~/airflow

    airflow webserver -p 9030

    airflow scheduler
fi
```

This is the code error.

The stderr from master node.

```
mv: cannot stat â€˜/home/hadoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jarâ€™: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access â€˜/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jarâ€™: No such file or directory
/emr/instance-controller/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/airflow_bootstrap.sh: line 25: /home/hadoop/airflowenv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
      Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
          status = self.run(options, args)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
          root=options.root_path,
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 687, in install
          requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 730, in uninstall
          paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
          renames(path, new_path)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 292, in renames
          shutil.move(old, new)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
          os.unlink(src)
      OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip'

You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-rmGy3J/sqlalchemy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-J6Ft9n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /mnt/tmp/pip-build-rmGy3J/sqlalchemy
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 693, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 817, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1018, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 237, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 208, in clobber
      os.makedirs(destdir)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3transfer'

/emr/instance-controller/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/airflow_bootstrap.sh: line 31: airflow: command not found
mv: cannot stat â€˜/home/hadoop/carriola/airflow.cfgâ€™: No such file or directory
/emr/instance-controller/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/airflow_bootstrap.sh: line 35: airflow: command not found
/emr/instance-controller/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/airflow_bootstrap.sh: line 37: airflow: command not found
```

Comment: This is being executed as the hadoop user, which has limited privileges. Permission errors are expected if you try to use pip to install modules at the system level without using the `--user` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cat /mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json | jq .isMaster
```

instead to find isMaster true or not.